# Source not found jre7 lib has no source attachment

Tags: java, eclipse

So I know in eclipse, when I hold `ctrl` key and move my mouse over to the class I created, I am able to click it and open the class. 
Now I was trying to do the same thing to the JRE system library classes, but I got

> source not found

Here is the screen shot:
[image]

As you can see I was trying to open us the `String` class but failed. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manged to got it working. It looks like I have to attach the source at the source not found page. And the source is a `zip` file called `src.zip`, which located at the jdk folder. Screen shot is attached.[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to download the java 1.7 jdk and attach it to your project.
That should do the trick.